# Debian wifi adapter unrecognized after install network-manager

Tags: debian, networking, wifi, drivers, networkmanager

When I first installed debian I used `wpa_supplicant` and `dhclient` to connect to my wifi which so far has worked great, but now I installed network-manager (nmcli) which right away when it finished installing, it disconnected me from my wifi and I cant seem to reconnect, I checked my wifi adapters with `nmcli dev status` and I get:

```
DEVICE  TYPE      STATUS       CONNECTION
wlp1s0  wifi      unavailable  --  
lo      loopback  unmanaged    --
```

I tried to connect to a wifi network with `nmcli device wifi connect <ssid> password <password>`
which returns:

```
Error: No network with SSID '<ssid>' found.
```

So just to double check if I had the name wrong I tried `nmcli dev wifi list` to scan for wifi networks, but this returns and empty table.

I think my wifi drivers are broken so please help, my laptop doesn't have an ethernet port so there is no way for me a download any packages with firmware.

Comment: I personally prefer connman for setting up network in gui.

Answer (score 1):

In tests, once I disabled the Wireless interface(s):

```
nmcli radio wifi off
```

then I got all of OP's symptoms when trying a known SSID (immediately, without scanning):

```
$ nmcli device wifi connect <ssid> password <password>
Error: No network with SSID '<ssid>' found.
$ nmcli dev status |grep ' wifi '
wlan0           wifi       unavailable             --         
$ nmcli dev wifi
IN-USE  BSSID  SSID  MODE  CHAN  RATE  SIGNAL  BARS  SECURITY 
$
```

Just enable it back (this includes doing the equivalent of `rfkill unblock ...` but also enables back NetworkManager handling, so `nmcli` should be used, not `rfkill`):

```
nmcli radio wifi on
```

to now get instead:

```
$ nmcli dev status |grep ' wifi '
wlan0           wifi       disconnected            --
```

Now scan results should be available again with `nmcli dev wifi list` and the connection attempt should work again with `nmcli device wifi connect <ssid> password <password>`.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it, after installing network-manager, it adds a couple of services that mess with everything.

I disabled them with

```
sudo systemctl stop NetworkManager
```

and

```
sudo systemctl disable NetworkManager-wait-online NetworkManager-dispatcher NetworkManager
```

If you have the same issue, I hope this helps.

**Edit:**

I just quickly wanted to add my source: https://linuxbabe.com/debian/connect-to-wi-fi-from-terminal-on-debian-wpa-supplicant

This is the exact same thing I used before I installed network-manager which ruined everything